# Change bucket to uniform access control

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a Bucket in Google Cloud. Now I want to switch "fine grained" Access Control to "uniform".
I can do this via console, but how can I change that setting via Terraform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found `uniform_bucket_level_access`.

And also needed to upgrade my Google Provider from *3.20.0*.